# How to use shopify session in php website

Tags: php, cakephp, shopify

I have an a website made in core-php/cakephp and i have also an shopify store . I need to use shopify user session use in my php site .if user login on my shopify store and after login he go to php site the session will continue in my php site . How can I create user in my php website when user create/login in my shopify store or How can I get user information from shopify store to my php website?

Comment: Please provide us with the code of your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Shopify provide facility of the webhooks which is called when a particular event is fire. Like customers create/delete/disable/enable/update on shopify site it also triggered the registered webhooks.

When use create a webhook in shopify store you have to pass URL where shopify will send data.
For more details looks at: 
https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/webhook

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.